# Android location contains random altitude values

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, android-location

I'm working on a GPS tracker app. Part of information I gather is user elevation during trip.

And I can't understand why do I get some random values for altitude. I test on Samsung S3 in a plain area without any mountains. And values I get for **altitude vary from -30 to +60 meters**.

I read something about altitude accuracy which can be +/- 15 meters. But in my case, the results I get are way above that threshold

Does anyone have any idea how to get accurate altitude? I'm not interested in querying any third-party API for that (like Google geocoder).

Thanks

Comment: I suggest that you try on "non samsung" devices to start with. Samsung location's are very buggy, and their forum is not helpful atall.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, altitude is not accurate on GPS, and very jumping.
You only can average over the last x seconds, asuming that the device does not change its real altitude fast.

You further can read the vertical accuracy, and ignore altituded exceeding a specific accuracy threshold (on ios I would use 30m, as vertical accuracy threshold)

Comment: Unfortunately, on Android no vertical accuracy is provided for any location point. And calculating the average may be a good idea, but it can also be a pain since the app allows user to modify the interval between two points. Therefore, the logic to calculate the avg value can get rather complicated